# Kinematic NavMesh Agents colliding

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my game, I have two enemies with NavMeshAgents, capsule colliders, and Rigidbodies. Both rigidbodies are set to kinematic. However, both objects still collide with each other. As far as I know, kinematic rigidbodies should not collide with other kinematic rigidbodies, so I don't know what is going on. Is it related to the NavMeshAgents? I am moving the enemies using NavMeshAgent.SetDestination() if that matters. Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this in your enemy script:

```cs
if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("enemy"))
    Physics.IgnoreCollision(collision.collider,gameObject.GetComponent<Collider>());
```

This will disable the collider if it runs into another gameobject tagged as "enemy".
Hope this helps!